# Grouping data and comparing it from excel in python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am working on a project using python to select certain values from an excel file. I am using the xlrd library and openpyxl library to do this.

The way the python program should we working is :

- Grouping all the data point entries that are in a certain card tase. These are marked in column E. For example, all of the entries between row 26 and row 28 are in Card Task A, and hence they should be grouped together. All entries without a “Card Task” value in column E should not be considered as anything.

Next…

- looking at the value from column N (lastExecTime) from a row and compare that time with the following value in column M
- If it is seen that the times overlap (column M is less than the previous N value) it will increment a variable called “count” . Count stores the number of times a procedure overlaps.

Finally…

- As for the output, the goal is to create a separate text file that displays which tasks are overlapping, and how many tasks overlap in a certain Card Task.

The problem that I am running into is that I cannot pair the data from a card task

Here is a sample of the excel data:

[The data (a picture of it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtpLH.png)

Here is a picture of more data (this will probably be more helpful)
[Click here for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOLgW.jpg)

And here is the code that I have written that tells me if there are multiple procedures going on:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook('LearnerSummaryNoFormat.xlsx')
sheet = book['Sheet1']


for row in sheet.rows:
     if ((row[4].value[:9]) != 'Card Task'):
         print ("Is not a card task: " + str(row[1].value))
```

Essentially my problem is that I am not able to compare all the values from one card task with each other.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read through the data once like you have already but store all rows with 'Card Task' in a separate list. Once you have a list of only card task items you can compare.

```
card_task_row_object_list = []
count = 0

for row in sheet.rows:
     if 'Card Task' in row[4]:
          card_task_row_object_list.append(row)
```

From here you would want to compare the time values. What are you needed to check, if two different card task times overlap?

(row 12: start, row 13: end)

```
def compare_times(card_task_row_object_list):
     for row in card_task_row_object_list:
          for comparison_row in card_task_row_object_list:
               if (comparison_row[12] <= row[13] && comparison_row[13] >= row[12])
                     # No overlap
               else
                     count+=1
```

Comment: I need to check if two different procedures in a Card Task overlap. So for example, based off column E, I would group all of the Card Task A procedures together (there are only 3), and I would use the M and N columns to compare their start and end times to see if they overlap. If they overlap, then increment count AND store which procedures overlap.

Comment: OK, so you would probably want to take what I wrote above and instead store matching card tasks in their own list rather than how I've done it which was storing anything with 'Card Task' in the column E string. Then you can pass each of those lists into the compare_times functions individually and handle the logic of counting/storing the things you need.

Comment: Perfect, and so how would I pass in which 'Card Task' I would want to go into the 'compare_times' method?

Comment: Well there are a few different ways you can accomplish that. Are you always going to have 'Card Task A', 'Card Task B', 'Card Task C' etc? If that's the case then you can change card_task_row_object_list = [] to something like card_task_a_row_object_list = [] and then card_task_b_row_object_list = [] and create one for each card task you need to check. From there you would need to change the structure of the first for each loop and have one specific to each individual card task i.e --> if row[4] == "Card Task A"

Comment: Yes, it goes from A, B, C, all the way to Z, but it will never reach till AA, AB, etc.

Comment: I'm sure there are more computationally efficient ways of doing that, this is a pretty slow way to do it so if you have a ton of data you might need to do it differently.

Comment: And then after that runs pass each of those lists to the compare_times function